# Ignorar todos arquivos exceto um especifico no GIT

Tags: github, git

Eu quero ignorar tudo da pasta "assets" exceto o arquivo "xmutarn.js", tentei assim no *.gitignore*:

```
!assets/script/xmutarn.js /assets
```

Mas não funciona, como posso resolver?

Meu .gitignore esta assim:

```
## Files to ignore
*.gitignore
*.bak

## Archives to ignore
changelog*

/index.php

## Folders to ignore
.idea/
sys/session
assets/
!assets/script/xmutarn.js
```

Comment: Por favor coloca aqui o código e não numa imagem. Porque tens um espaço a seguir ao nome do ficheiro?

Comment: Se você já commitou o arquivo alguma vez, será necessário fazer `git rm --cached nomearquivo.js`.

Comment: Boa tarde Vinicius, não poste fotos de códigos, se é código simplesmente o copie aqui, assim facilita as pessoas depurarem exatamente da maneira que você fez. Usar fotos de códigos só funcionaria se todo mundo tivesse um software de OCR, então evite a não ser que seja algo pertinente ao IDE que esta usando, o que não é o caso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu não entendi o `/assets` no final de:

```
!assets/script/xmutarn.js /assets
```

O sinal de exclamação que dizer "negação" `!` ou seja o arquivo na linha não sera ignorado. *Acredito* que pra ignorar o **conteúdo** da pasta `assets` seria algo como:

```
assets/*
```

Se fizer assim vai ignorar a pasta toda (corrija-me se estiver enganado):

```
assets/
```

Então deve ficar assim:

```
assets/*
!assets/script/xmutarn.js
```

Outro detalhe, conforme o [@DanielGomes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24790911#24790911) encontrou no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987162/1518921) é necessário adicionar `!*/` sempre que se tratar de sub-diretórios, aparentemente não precisa ser no final como dito em https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227991/1518921 e https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025106/1518921

Basicamente, primeiro fazemos uma *blacklist* e depois uma *whitelist*

O código todo deve ficar algo como:

```
## Files to ignore
*.gitignore
*.bak

## Archives to ignore
changelog*

/index.php

## Folders to ignore
.idea/
sys/session
assets/*

#Whitelist a seguir

!*/
!assets/script/xmutarn.js
```

Se não funcionar, tem um detalhe, pode ser que ao usar assim `assets/*` ele force ignorar as pastas também no caso a pasta `./assets/script`, então você pode tentar fazer as regras pra cada pasta dentro de `./assets` ao invés da pasta toda.

Comment: Já tentei de tudo por isso aquele /assets no final, mas não funciona de jeito nenhum, testei com outras pastas e funciona, exceto com a pasta assets

Comment: Mas exatamente o que ocorre, ele ignora todos arquivos, ou ele não esta ignorando nenhum? @Vinicius

Comment: Ignorando todos e esse que não é pra ignorar ele ignora também, mas pode deixar resolvi de outro modo, só que não muito produtivo, ignorando as pastas e os arquivos dentro da pasta script

Comment: @Vinicius Muito estranho funcionar com todas as pastas, menos com a pasta `assets/` - sugestão: inclua o seu `.gitignore` completo na pergunta.

Comment: @Vinicius Não é porque você resolveu de outro modo que a sua duvida não irá servi pra outras pessoas, não custa continuar tentando quando tiver um tempo, amanhã instalo o `git` e irei testar. Até amanhã.

Comment: @DanielGomes também achei estranho, provavelmente ele adicionou algo a mais que não foi citado aqui.

Comment: Adicionei tudo que esta no meu .gitignore apesar de que quando eu coloco ## ele transforma em titulo

Comment: @Vinicius mas eu disse que usar `assets/` ira ignorar o diretório todo e que o correto é `assets/*`, veja na resposta como ficou o código todo.

Comment: Ainda não funciona, com nenhum arquivo da pasta assets

Comment: Veja no estouro de pilha, @GuilhermeNascimento...

Comment: @Vinicius resposta editada.