# Como ignorar um arquivo depois de já estarem em um commit?

Tags: git

Adicionei num repositório meu algumas imagens acidentalmente.

Porém agora quero ignorá-las, porém não está obedecendo os dados que foram adicionados em `.gitignore`

Exemplo:

```
public/imagens/*
```

Como faço para que um arquivo ou pasta, que já fazem parte dos commits anteriores, passarem a ser ignorados no repositório atual?

## atualização

O @GuilhermeNascimento solicitou que eu demonstrasse como foi criado o arquivo `.gitignore` no meu caso específico.

Ele está da seguinte forma:

```
public/solicitacoes/**/*
public/fichas_tecnicas/**/*
public/imagens/**/*
public/xls/**/*
```

Comment: O que pode ser melhorado na pergunta? Por favor, comente, para que eu possa ser mais claro.

Comment: Wallace eu não tenho certeza, mas veja se isso tem haver com o problema http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93135/3635 - claro que no caso queria ignorar a maioria, mas com algumas exceções. Acho que a pergunta está OK, só falta mesmo adicionar como esta a pasta de estrutura e confirmar se o .gitignore é só essa linha, porque se tiverem mais pode ser um conflito de "lógica".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade o problema é o seguinte: uma pasta de imagens está no repositório. Com o tempo, muitos testes e muitos uploads, ela ficou grande. Não quero tê-la mais no meu repositório, com os arquivo sendo adicionados ao commit. Quero fazer com que essa pasta ou arquivos sejam ignorados. Porém parece que depois de estar no repositório ele não quer obedecer o .gitignore

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fiz um teste aqui com um arquivo que já estava antes e funcionou. Acho que estou confuso quanto ao funcionamento do .gitignore

Comment: Eu entendi isso Wallace e tenho uma noção de como funciona :) - Só queria saber a estrutura de pastas, por que a "ordem" de exclusão do .gitignore pode afetar o processo. As vezes é necessário criar a whitelist depois da blackslist (não sei se esse é o termo), note também que se tiver mais arquivos para ignorar em um nivel superior a `public/images` pode ser um conflito de regras. Só queria mesmo uma confirmação de que `public/imagens/*` é a única regra.

Comment: Parece que o .gitignore vai ignorar apenas arquivos que não foram rastreados(*tracked files*). Uma vez que você já adicionou os arquivos no repositório (git add) tente executar o comando abaixo e verifique se ele passa a ser ignorado (fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git):

    **git rm nome_arquivo --cached ** Caso resolva, posto como resposta.

Comment: Só uma nota isso ignora arquivos dentro outras pastas dentro de imagens `public/imagens/**/*` e não a pasta de imagens propriamente dita, quero dizer.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como faço para remover uma pasta do histórico do Git?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/584/13561), nessa resposta é utilizado `git filter-branch`, que reescreve todo o histórico e não é um procedimento recomendado para repositórios públicos, pois será necessário clonar novamente o projeto

Comment: Esperem eu não to entendo, pensei que o problema era evitar de adicionar e não remover antigos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O `.gitignore` serve para ignorar apenas arquivos não rastreados, ou seja, a partir do momento em que um `git add` é  utilizado para rastrear as mudanças do arquivo, o `.gitignore` não poderá ignorar esses arquivos.

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected; see the NOTES below for details.  (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Caso não tenha feito o `commit` ainda, utilize:

- `git reset <arquivo-ou-diretório>`

Caso já tenha realizado um `commit`, utilize:

- `git rm --cached <arquivo>`
- `git rm -r --cached <diretório>`

> ***git-rm*** - Remove files from the working tree and from the index
>
> **-r**
>   Allow recursive removal when a leading directory name is given.
>
> **--cached**
>   Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working 
>   tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

Existe ainda uma terceira situação que talvez possa interessar a alguns, onde o git mantém uma cópia do arquivo e para de realizar atualizações nela. (útil para manter um arquivo de modelo quando se trabalha em equipe)

- `git update-index --assume-unchanged <arquivo-ou-diretório>`

> ***git-update-index*** - Register file contents in the working tree to the index
>
> **--[no-]assume-unchanged**
>      When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated. Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths. When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

Fonte: https://git-scm.com/docs

Answer (score 2):

Para o git ignorar um determinado arquivo, esse arquivo não pode estar no repositório.

Caso você tenha commitado ele anteriormente e queira remover, você tem que remover ele do git para o gitignore passar a funcionar.

```
#gitignore
....
arquivo_a_ser_ignorado.txt
....

git rm caminho/arquivo_a_ser_ignorado.txt
git commit -m "removendo arquivo"
git push origin master
```

Se der um git status a partir dai, o seu arquivo não aparecerá como algo para subir pro git.