# Ignorando arquivos pelo .gitignore

Tags: gitlab, git

Uso o `GitLab` como repositório para um projeto `Android`. Quero ignorar os arquivos de da pasta `openCVLibrary320` na hora do `commit/push`. Digitei a pasta da seguinte maneira no arquivo `.gitignore`:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
/openCVLibrary320
```

Alterei um arquivo qualquer dentro da pasta `openCVLibrary320`. Ao dar o `commit` era pra ignorar esse arquivo, porém ele aparece para ser comitado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que devo fazer ?

Comment: Este arquivo já foi commitado alguma vez? Ou seja, ele já existe no repositório?

Comment: sim, subi apenas ele no repositório

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ignorar um arquivo depois de já estarem em um commit?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113524/como-ignorar-um-arquivo-depois-de-j%c3%a1-estarem-em-um-commit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se o arquivo/pasta já existe no repositório, não basta apenas colocá-lo no *gitignore*, também é preciso removê-lo do repositório. Em outras palavras, é necessário avisar ao GIT para que pare de "observar" o arquivo/pasta em questão.

O comano para isto é o `rm --cached <file>`, no seu caso, fica assim

> ```
> git rm --cached openCVLibrary320/
> ```

Comment: funcionou, obrigado

Comment: É isso mesmo, acontecia comigo direto. Só toma cuidado caso você fizer o push direto no servidor, como eu faço, pois ele deletar os conteúdos indexados anteriormente.

Comment: Sim, @WallaceMaxters. É exatamente esta a intenção. Se você quer manter os arquivos no servidor, mas não "trackear" as mudanças precisa do "assume unchanged" e não colocar no gitignore.

Comment: Isso vai salvar muitas vidas. 1+