# Como enviar todos os arquivo do diretório exceto um específico?

Tags: git

Gostaria de enviar todos os arquivos do diretório, exceto o `config.php`. Basicamente uso o comando `git add .` para adicionar todos os arquivos, porém quando possui poucos arquivos editados, faço desta forma:

```
git add arquivo1.php
git add arquivo2.php
git add arquivo3.php
```

O arquivo `config.php` na minha maquina está de um jeito, porém no *server* possui outras variáveis específicas. Nem sempre preciso enviar o `config.php`. Gostaria de um comando para enviar todos os arquivos exceto este. Sei que existe o `.gitignore` e também essa pergunta sobre [Ignorar todos arquivos exceto um especifico no GIT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93126/ignorar-todos-arquivos-exceto-um-especifico-no-git), porém as vezes preciso enviar o arquivo `config.php`, sem que ignore-o, quando há alguma configuração específica.

No "pseudocomando" seria algo como:

```
git add . exceto config.php
```

Como enviar todos os arquivo do diretório exceto um específico?

Comment: E porque não fazer uso do `.gitignore` para facilitar o processo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento porque não é sempre que preciso ignora-lo. Se fosse fixo, já teria colocado lá. Seria algo mesmo como o pseudocomando, "Adiciona tudo e ignora esse"... `git add tudo exceto config.php`

Comment: Entendo, mas o `.gitignore` não precisa ser pra sempre, você pode edita-lo a qualquer momento na sua máquina local, ou seja ele é um arquivo de ajustável a sua necessidade para qualquer momento.

Comment: Ah, entendi, você não quer ignorar o arquivo, você quer ignorar as modificações, é isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ignorar mudanças/modificações no GIT

Se quer ignorar modificações em um arquivo especifico "servidor git", o que você pode tentar é forçar assumir que não houve mudanças (creio que é necessário apenas uma vez):

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged foo/bar/baz/config.php
```

Assim o arquivo que já existe no repositório não será removido, mas não será mais atualizado, mas se fizer alguma modificação que necessite que atualize o `config.php` então use:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged foo/bar/baz/config.php
```

E então no próximo update use novamente o `--assume-unchanged` no `config.php`

### Ignorar enviar (remover o arquivo)

Se quer ignorar que um arquivo seja enviado pode usar o o `.gitignore` e ajusta-lo se desejar enviar posteriormente, o `.gitignore` é um arquivo editável a qualquer momento e você o usa como desejar.

Se adicionar:

```
 config.php
```

Além de não enviar, se existir algum `config.php` no repositório ele será removido de lá.

Answer (score 1):

Faça a adição normal e peça um retrocesso do `config.php`.

```
git add -u
git reset -- config.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione somente o que vc alterou:

```
git add -u
```

**Sumario**

```
git add -A   Tudo que estiver em staging
git add .    Tudo em stage, e modificados 
git add -u   stage modificados e deletados, novos ignorados.
```

Comment: Mas `config.php` eu alterei, mas não quero envia-lo. Nem sempre preciso envia-lo.